# How to send a .cpp file in json format using a simple python script

Tags: python, json

```
I am having not to use any .cpp library to serialise the contents of(.cpp) file. I just need the file to be transported and stored in a server. The idea is client sends/posts the file in Json format using REST API to the server. Would be helpful to know a simple python script if anyone has done this before.
This is the simple script that works locally. But I also have a web service 
<pre>import json

data=[]
flag=False

# filename, mode: r for reading
with open('example.cpp','r') as f:
 for line in f:
   data.append(line)

# Using built in function json()
dataJ=jsonify(data)
print dataJ
```

This is the input file, so basically a cpp file (Arduino based program) that will be wrapped in JSON. The output will be stored as a blob in the server. Also, about jsonify I think its my mistake it should be json.dump(data) instead of jsonify.

```
 {
            "guid" : "abcdefg",
            "platformio.ini" : {
                "platform": "atmelavr",
                "framework": "arduino",
                "board": "uno",
                // "board_mcu":,
                // "board_f_cpu":,
                // "lib_install":,
                // "lib_use":,
                // "lib_ignore":,
                // "lib_dfcyclic":
            },
```

`#include \"Arduino.h\"
    // the setup function runs once when you press reset or power the board
    void setup() {
      // initialize digital pin 13 as an output.
      pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
    }

    // the loop function runs over and over again forever
    void loop() {
      digitalWrite(13, HIGH);   // turn the LED on (HIGH is the voltage level)
      delay(1000);              // wait for a second
      digitalWrite(13, LOW);    // turn the LED off by making the voltage LOW
      delay(1000);              // wait for a second
    }",

        "status" : "null"
    }</pre>`

Comment: Can you give an example of an input cpp file and an output json file? There is no set way to convert a c++ source file to json.

Comment: The script you have shown us does not work.   `jsonify()` is not defined.

Comment: I do apologise, it should be json.dump(data). I was using Flask before and i mixed up.